# Data from multiple tables. One table into array row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have problem with one query which get data from 2 tables:

```
SELECT  C.*, US.* 
FROM `".DB_TABLE_USERS."` US 
LEFT JOIN ".DB_TABLE_AUTH." AS AU ON AU.auth_user_id=US.".DB_TABLE_USERS_ROW_ID."
LEFT JOIN ".DB_TABLE_CLINICS." C ON C.".DB_TABLE_CLINIC_ROW_ID." = US.".DB_TABLE_USERS_ROW_CLINIC."
WHERE AU.auth_code_id = '".$_SESSION[ AUTH_SESSION_AUTHID ]."'
```

Result is sth like this( I've removed some fields from here ):

```
Array
(
    [clinic_id] => 1
    [clinic_row1] => Row1
    [clinic_row2] => Row2
    [user_id] => 8
    [user_username] => owner
)
```

But I would like to have sth like this:

```
Array
(

    [user_id] => 8
    [user_username] => owner
    [clinic_data] => Array (
        [clinic_id] => 1
        [clinic_row1] => Row1
        [clinic_row2] => Row2
    )
)
```

Is it possible? I've tried

```
C.* AS clinic_data
```

But this doesn't work.
Any one can help?

Comment: From mysql you'll only get unidimensional arrays. You need to post-process it manually in your app.

Comment: yes but that needs to be done from PHP while you generate the array it can not be done from mysql end.